# How can I download a season Baseball Reference data with player IDs?

Tags: baseball, statistics

Is there a simple way to download a season of player data from Baseball-Reference.com that includes their player ID?

I can download data with the player names, but I need the player ID they use to make it easier to query and make lists across seasons with unique players.

Comment: Best place to ask would be the baseball-reference.com support email address, I would have thought of

Comment: Can you concatenate player name and birth date to create a unique ID?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found an option either through Baseball-reference to download the stats and have a player ID included per row. However, I know of the [Lahman Database](http://www.seanlahman.com/baseball-archive/statistics/)
that provides season stats and includes a player ID.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was afraid of.  The 2015 isn't out yet unfortunately, but it may be the only option.

Comment: Yea I think your right the 2015 is probably still in the works

Comment: I was able to take an online course through Boston College MOOC, they focused on the Lehman Database to gain statistical insights on the players/teams

Answer (score 0):

You can get the player_id if you scrape the HTML instead of using the tools on the website.

[image: BBREF-Player_ID-HTML]

If you inspect the element you will see that the link in the table to the player page has the player_id. I think this player ID is based on the Retrosheet ID, but I could be wrong there.